# Lester will not start the Fleeca Job. Am I missing something?

Tags: xbox-one, grand-theft-auto-online

I have completed the Diamond Casino heist, and the Cayo Perico Heist, and the Doomsday Heist Act 2. According to Rockstar, I should be easily able to start the basic heists. I own a high end apartment, and am level 62

Comment: Are you sure that you have completed all of the heist preps? Aka have you taken the Armored Kuruma from the parking garage?